# Prevent clicking a link if scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have long vertical list of links that user can scroll through, and I need to prevent triggering a `click` event (touch) on this links if user scrolls.

In current scenario, when user start scrolling by tapping over the link, it also triggers a `click` on link. Which is obviously bad. So, is there any way to prevent such a behavior?

Comment: did you change the touch behavior? On my phone if I start scrolling on a link then the link doesn't get triggered...

Comment: In my own experience on mobile browsing I have run into this problem before - Upvote.

I have not expended any effort to try to curb this behavior, but off the top of my head. You could possibly create a larger element that seperates the actual link and the rest of the _item_. Will look at this post closely...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/132/)**

We could use a flag in this case to prevent `click` event just during the scroll and enable it after the scroll stop.

To listen on scroll stop you could use jQuery’s data method that gives us the ability to associate arbitrary data with DOM nodes and using `setTimeout()` function that will check every `250ms` if the user still trigger the scroll, and if not it will change the flag :

```
var disable_click_flag = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    disable_click_flag = true;

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));

    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        disable_click_flag = false;
    }, 250));
});

$("body").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    if( disable_click_flag ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.