# Javascript scrolling without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to amend my page clicking inside divs and links whilst i'm scrolling the page?

My page is very long and full of tables, links, buttons, etc, and as i'm scrolling the page on a mobile device, i end up clicking links and navigating away whilst i'm trying to just smooth scroll!

Thanks

Comment: Try lazy loading on scrolling to bottom of page

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38205159/1650200) on a very similar question.