# jQuery: Prevent click on the scroll while using touchscreen device

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch-event

I have one problem where users on the scroll fire `click` event and open the gallery accidental.

Here is my current code:

```
gallery.on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /** SOME MY CODE **/
});
```

How to prevent this click when user scrolling and fire it ONLY when user click to it on the mobile browser or any other touchscreen device?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204562/prevent-clicking-a-link-if-scroll-on-mobile